# open an excel file on export access vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Set wbTarget1 = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Trk_Insp_1204_10_08_2016.xlsx")

The location is different on the other machines, ie the owner is different. Can I use current.path?  Can I use wild cards or

~\Trk_Insp_1204_10_08_2016.xlsx

I saw a reference that mentioned you can truncate the path if the excel file resided in the current directory the access DB was located.

Dennis

Comment: Use `Environ$("USERPROFILE")`.

Comment: http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/get_mdb_database_path.html

Comment: Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Environs$("USERPROFILE") & "\Dropbox\Trk_Insp_1204_10_08_2016.xlsx")   I get Sub or function not defined, centered around the Environs$   I'm not sure how to use this function, I've done some searching and can't seem to find the specific help I need.

Comment: If your Excel file is located in the same folder as your Access DB then you can use the information at the link I posted

Answer (score 0):

Please make a simple test sub and test:

```
Sub EnvTest()
 Dim S as String

 S = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Dropbox\Trk_Insp_1204_10_08_2016.xlsx"
 Debug.Print S
End Sub
```